# Remove all files from Mongo GridFs (both files and chunks)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, gridfs

I'm writing some tests agains MongoDb GridFs and want to make sure that I start each test with a clean slate. So I want to remove everything, both from fs_files and fs_chunks.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GridFs has its own database then I would just drop the database via mongo shell with [db.dropDatabase()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/). Alternately if there are collections you would like to keep apart from fs_files and fs_chunks in the database you could drop the collections explicitly with [db.collection.drop()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/drop/). For both you can run via command from a driver rather than through the shell if desired.

Comment: That worked but now I got a connection problem... Ok, not related to this. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove GridFS, try it like (pyMongo Case)

```
for i in fs.find(): # or fs.list()
    print fs.delete(i._id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to remove all files and chunks is

```
let bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, { bucketName: 'gridfsdownload' });
bucket.drop(function(error) { /* do something */ });
```

This will remove the collections as well. If you want to keep the collections, you need to 
to do something like this:

```
let allFiles = db.collection('uploaded.file').find({}).toArray();
for (let file of allFiles) {
    await bucket.delete(file._id);
}
```